# Category plot on 1's and 0's from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, plot

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {'a': [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], 'b': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 'c': [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] ...}
```

Goal : Make a category bar plot where x axis is the key name and the y axis is the proportion of 0 and 1.

```
key = dict.keys()
values = dict.values()
```

I know that using count() can get me the number of 1's and 0's

```
values.get('a').count(1)
```

How do I draw a category plot using a dictionary of lists?

Comment: What have you tried doing?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It requires the `pandas` library.

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'a': [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], 'b': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 'c': [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df = [df[col].value_counts().to_frame().T for col in ['a', 'b', 'c']]

df = pd.concat(df)

df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = {
    'a': [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    'b': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    'c': [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
}

keys = list(data.keys()) # ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I would use list comprehension to build a list with the counts:

```
count_zero = [data[k].count(0) for k in keys] # [7, 1, 7]
count_ones = [data[k].count(1) for k in keys] # [2, 8, 2]
```

And finally plot the data:

```
# Create the bar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ind = list(range(1, len(data) + 1)) # [1, 2, 3, ...] horizontal location of the bars

bars = plt.bar(ind, count_zero)
bars = plt.bar(ind, count_ones, bottom=count_zero)

ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(keys) # labels: a, b, c
ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
ax.set_title('StackOverflow')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]